# Замыкание в Java Script

Tags: javascript

```
function makeAdder(x) {

    return function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };

};

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

Всем привет! Не понятен пример замыкание в данном коде ..

Как выходит 7 и как выходит 12 ? Кто-то может объяснить Flow данной функции ?

Comment: Я бы не сказал что примеры одинаковые, не смотря на ту же тему.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, принцип работы один и тот же: makeAdder возвращает функцию которая **помнит** `x`

Comment: тут просто не понятно что происходит с y , "тоесть что происходит за кулисами , как решается что будет возврат только x ? "

Comment: эм, что значит _возврат только y_? а что значит _возврат только x_?

Comment: вы мне ответили  makeAdder возвращает функцию которая помнит x , то есть возврашается x ..

Comment: Эм... нет, не _то есть возврашается x_. Оно просто запомнилось где-то :-) не особо принципиально где. И при вызове возвращенной функции используется

Comment: Помнится Вы говорили что знакомы с java, так вот замыкание === лямбда выражение.